# Cloning xfs filesystem using cpio?

Tags: cpio, cloning

I need your help in cloning 28TB xfs filesystem I used the following script:

```
/backuptacs.sh >> /backuptacs.log
```

And the script is:

```
#!/bin/ksh
echo "++++++++++++++++ Start Date is `date`+++++++++++++ "
cd /tacs1/conq/hhl_imgs
find . -depth -print | cpio -pdmv /tacs2/conq/hhl_imgs
echo "++++++++++++++++ Completion Date is `date`+++++++++"
echo "========================================================"
```

With 31 GB of free memory when I run the above script I noticed too mush usage of memory. In two hours time free memory dropped to 23 GB. I can see from top that 8 GB is used and keep increasing.

Comment: What process is using the memory?  Or is it cache?

Comment: more than 20 processes cpio - smb etc

Comment: Why are you running the script 20 times?

Comment: Sorry, only one process for cpio and one process for find and the other process are different one..